# Client and PHP backend communication: Sokets, Stream, TCP/UDP?

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, stream, udp

**Short version:** I want to connect a Client to a PHP server, but i have a limitation on the server of 10 PHP scripts running  at the same time.

Question is: **What is the best way to connect a client with PHP script, while staying under the limitation?**

**Long version:**
My previous questions shows what i am really after, but here it is again:
I want to develop a a webchat using Java applet as the client side, and PHP as the back end server. Under normal circumstances I wouldn't ask a question like this just use the first thing that google pops up to my search. but right now i'm not under normal circumstances, but under restrictions: Server usage, as in my hosting isa shared account hosting, and 10 Entry processes(aka the number of PHP scripts running at the same time.) I need to make a server to my chat with these in minds, and lowering the performance as much as i can.

I did develop a Client/server connection using TCP in Delphi, but that was long ago, and i forgot much of it. And Now i try to resurface it, i realize i didn't know much about it.

So I got several questions, based on my researches:

**What is a socket?**
I did goggle this but i didn't find a really clear answer to this. This is the standard way of two programs communicating with each other right? and this where maybe one of my wrong knowledge is...

**Is TCP/UDP protocol by Sockets?**
I dont even know how to explain this question of mine...

**What is stream exactly?**
What i know from my C++ knowledge is its the ability to open files in binary form, and read from it from any point. I might be wrong because my C++ knowledge is old too.

Also i read about PHP sockets, and i found about that its capable to listen to a port with [socket_create_listen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create-listen.php) but **my concern is that does this scrip runs actively? like an infinitive loop? I'm asking this because the 10 process limitation.**
And if i initiate a TCP Connection with a client does the script runs in an infinite loop again? **does it counts on the active processes?**

I know UDP doesn't need an active connection, because it just send it en masse and forgets about it terminating the script when it ends, but i don't know about TCP.

Sorry for the long post, and the many questions, and thank you for any help you can offer.

**EDIT:** I Forgot about GET/POST methods!
As i said that I'm planing a webchat and they need to communicate, but aside from direct connection there is the GET/POST method as well, which  the script quickly does and terminates the script, but again the 10 process limit, **what happens when 11 process tries to run at the same time?**

**Also is there a way to limit the simultaneously running processes? or put into a queue and wait till the others finish?**

Comment: Contract a better hosting server. Hostgator.com accepts up to 25 processes at the same time in the starter plan.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is limited to only 10 concurrent threads, this is a hard limit and you can't do much.  What you can do is to make the request as small as possible, and have as less things as possible resolved by php. So the possibility of concurrency would be very small.

Ideally, all your php's will start and exit very quickly, often redirecting the user to static content (html, js, img and css files).

Maybe you can make your whole webapp a lot of html files, and have some ajax.php file for the server communication...

Comment: yes i know its very limiting, but i want to work with this because its experience. also forgot to put there two more questions, which i just did.

Comment: I still think some sort of "api" will solve your problem. But what I don't know if your problem is feasible at all. I think your problem is solved if you can fullfill 10 request in exactly or less than one second. But that is not possible if all of them need 1 second and one of them more than 1 second. So the limitation is not really on the architecture,....  maybe the problem is imposible to solve the way you define it.